# How to query by object's object property with MongoDb Driver

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, mongodb-.net-driver, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm doing a .net core web api using mongodb driver to access my database.

I have this document's structure

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"ParticipantIdentities" : [
    {
        "ParticipantId" : 1,
        "Player" : {
            "AccountId" : 45678945,
            "AnotherProps" :"values"
            }
    }
    [Another arrays items]
  }
```

I want to fiter using `object.ParticipantIdentities.Player.AccountId`
I tried this way

```
var filter = Builders<Match>.Filter.Where(e => e.ParticipantIdentities.Where(p => p.Player.AccountId == AccountId).Count() > 1);
var result = await _context.Matches.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

And it threw an exception saying the .Count() is not supported.
I'm noob with mongodb queries yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
var filter = Builders<Match>.Filter.Eq("ParticipantIdentities.Player.AccountId", accountId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.i'll try it later and let you know if it worked.